# Cannot make POST Request with AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, afnetworking-2

**************EDITED*******************

I am relatively new to iOS and I want to make a post request using the following code:

I am getting a **NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://xxxxxx-xxxxxx/xxxx/xxxx}}, com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response= { URL: https://xxxxxx/xxx/xxxx/xxxxxs }**

```
        AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
        AFJSONRequestSerializer *requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

        [requestSerializer setValue:token1 forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
        [requestSerializer setValue:@"PP" forHTTPHeaderField:@"x-service-code"];
        [requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        [requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [manager setRequestSerializer:requestSerializer];


        NSDictionary *params = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                token.tokenId, @"payment_method_nonce",
                                details.city, @"city",
                                details.address1,  @"address1",
                                details.state, @"state",
                                details.zipcode, @"zip",
                                nil];



        [manager POST:url parameters:params

             success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject)
         {
             NSLog(@"SUCCEEDED");
         }
             failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error)
         {
             loadingOverlay.hidden = YES;
             NSLog(@"FAILED %@",error);


         }];
```

I have found out what the issue is: I need to send params as raw JSON and it's not doing that. How do I achieve this?

I want params to go in raw format i.e.

{"payment_method_nonce":"tok_xxxxxxxx"}

Comment: `unacceptable content-type: text/html`. Try to add `text\html` to the accepted content-type.

Comment: did not work + our server does not accept that format. I have verified that the issue is not headers but the parameter body. it needs to be sent as raw json. how do I convert params to Raw JSON?

Comment: How can I make a post request with address and token and other details sent as body with JSON format?

Comment: Since you set the `requestSerializer` as a `AFJSONRequestSerializer` one, it should itself transform the params into JSON and put them into the body. It does in a few words: NSDictionary ---(NSJSONSerialization)--> NSData (JSON representation) --> theNS(Mutable)Request.htttpBody = theJSONNSData.

Comment: I don't know what the problem is. Can I try using constructing WithBodyBlocks?

Comment: Here is a similar problem [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41605360/5163488).
Hope it will help.
Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Solved it I used a NSMutableDictionary instead:

```
[paymentDetails setObject:token.tokenId forKey:@"payment_method_nonce"];
            [paymentDetails setObject:details.address1 forKey:@"address1"];
            [paymentDetails setObject:details.city forKey:@"city"];
            [paymentDetails setObject:details.state forKey:@"state"];
            [paymentDetails setObject:details.zipcode forKey:@"zip"];
```

and used AFHTTPRequestOperationManager instead of AFHTTPSessionManager

Comment: Seems like the `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` was the solution; not `NSMutableDictionary`. `NSMutableDictionary` and `NSDictionary` should result in the same `params` for the request.