# Post method using Afnetworking in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, json, afnetworking

How to write the code to sending POST method for the below JSON format using Afnetworking.

```
{
Media
  {
      Photo : image.jpg, 
      UserId : 2
  },
Personal
  {
      Name : aaa, 
      Age   : 30
  }, 
Education
  {
    College : xxx, 
    Course : yyy    

  }, 
}
```

Comment: Where's your code?  Please see [Ask].  You also didn't even bother to take the 2-minute site [tour].

Answer (score 0):

Obviously that's not quite the actual format, but we can guess what you might have meant. Clearly, if those numeric values (the user id and age) are expected as strings, then quote then, but hopefully it illustrates what the Objective-C representation of that dictionary might look like:

```
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"Media": @{@"Photo": @"image.jpg", @"UserId": @2}, @"Personal": @{@"Name": @"aaa", @"Age": @30}, @"Education": @{@"College": @"xxx", @"Course": @"yyy" }};
```

Then you can post it as JSON like so:

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

[manager POST:@"https://yoururl.com" parameters:parameters progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"responseObject = %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    NSLog(@"error %@", error);
}];
```

And if your server doesn't support HTTPS, but only HTTP, then you might have to alter your `Info.plist`'s "App Transport Security Settings" to "Allow Arbitrary Loads".

[image]

Comment: Thanks Rob, How can I send "image.jpg" , Is it need to convert formdata like this,                                                    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *requestManager;

[requestManager POST:KAPIUploadOutfit parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) 
{
        [formData appendPartWithFileURL:fileURL name:@"photo_url" fileName:filename mimeType:@"image/png" error:nil];
    }

Comment: Sure, but that's not JSON, which you said you wanted to use. It is a `multipart/form-data` request. It's good way to send files, and for sending form values (i.e. pairs of keys/names and values), but not for sending a structured JSON (or at least without some silliness like putting JSON inside `multipart/form-data` request). So, you have a choice: Use `multipart/form-data` and simplify the structure of the rest of the request, or use JSON, but then you have to convert the image to some text representation within the JSON (e.g. base-64 encode), which you'll have to decode on server end..

Comment: Thanks for your answer Rob.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly make a dictionary of params you want to send

```
NSDictionary *params = @{
                                     @"contact_no":@"9898989898",
                                     @"password":@"••••••••••"
                                     };
```

Then write the following code

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *operationManager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    operationManager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    operationManager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
operationManager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/json", @"text/javascript", @"text/html", nil];
        [operationManager POST:urlString parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){
            NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);

        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
            if (failure)
                NSLog(@"%@",error.localizedDescription);
        }];
```

You can neglect the line in which i am setting the `acceptableContentTypes`.

Hope this will help.